# How to test for active options in ash shell?

Tags: bash, busybox

In bash, it is possible to check for active option with -o: such as [ -o nounset  ] && echo "Option -u active"

But (d)ash (the shell included in busybox) does not seem to recognize -o in tests.

How to test for options in ash/dash? Or, maybe, is there other hack specific to busybox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer:
(Thanks to folks on the busybox mailing list)

Special variable $- expands to string of all active option letters. 
This works on ash/dash and bash as well.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

"set -o" prints the list of all known options, with their states as "on" or "off".

"set +o" prints the same, but instead of "option on/off the output format is "set +o option" or "set -o option".

Grep that.

Thanks everyone who wanted to help ;)